# Hibernate foreign key redundant call

Tags: spring, hibernate, orm

I have a hibernate entity class

```java
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private Boolean visible;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Category parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Builder.Default
    private List<Category> children = new ArrayList<>();

    private UUID budgetId;
}
```

And I'm trying to update it data including parent. I have only id of this parent and because in the table we have parent_id it will be stupid to call for full parent item by id to only set it on entity. Do you have any idea to avoid that redundant call to database?

Comment: what about getting reference by id. A good article about this topic [spring-data-jpa-findbyid](https://vladmihalcea.com/spring-data-jpa-findbyid/)

Comment: @AndreiLisa looks awesemo, I search something like this

Answer (score 0):

You can just use "stub" entity.

```
Category parent= new Category();
parent.setId(parentId);
category.setParent(parent);
```

Comment: Don't I update parent object with nulls in this case?

Comment: No, if you dont save parent entity explicitly

Answer (score 0):

This is a very odd way to model an entity(-relation).

It is usually bad practice to model an entity in both directions. Because when you load one, you will be able to access the other no matter what.

```java
@Entity
class A {
    @Column
    private B b;
}

@Entity
class B {
    @Column
    private A a;
}
```

In a scenario where you want them both to coexist without a connection and connect them later on, then they should be free of references to each other, and you would need another entity which acts like a link for both.

```java
@Entity
class A {
}

@Entity
class B {
}

@Entity
class MyLink
{
    @Column
    private A a;
    @Column
    private B b;
}
```

If you want to model a tree, decide which direction is more suitable for reading the tree a bottom-up or top-down approach and reference only one direction but not both. And especially not eagerly loaded.

**Top-down**

```java
@Entity
class Node {
    @OneToMany
    List<Node> children;
}
```

**Bottom-up**

```java
@Entity
class Node {
    @Column
    Node parent;
}
```

And lastly, think about what each node should contain and if the identity of a node matters. Maybe you come to the conclusion that they have [value semantic](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/ValueObject.html). In that case, you would have an entity named `Tree` and it would reference a tree of nodes, which in itself would not be entities.